# How to calculate sum using variadic generic lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, generics, lambda, c++14, variadic

I wanted to write a generic sum function like the following one but not in template syntax but in lambda syntax:

```
template<typename T>
auto Sum(T lastSummand)
{
    return lastSummand;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
auto Sum(T firstSummand, Ts... restSummands)
{
    return firstSummand + Sum(restSummands...);
}
```

Because generic lambdas are mapped to templates it should be possible to do something like:

```
auto sum = [](auto firstSummand, auto... restSummands) { ... };
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the recursion using lambdas. Searching in this and other locations did not bring forward much.

Comment: This won't work for the simple reason that you need a specialization in order to cover the end case. You need at least two lambdas.

Comment: I don't like where c++ is going these days.

Comment: @Sam Varshavichik: How would you go about it using two lambdas?

Comment: @KitFisto: You can't, the template recursion approach requires that they have the same name/overload each other.  With two lambdas that isn't possible, because you get two different classes, while you need two `operator()` implementations in the same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++14 you don't actually need recursion to do that with generic lambdas.
As an example, you can do this:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    auto l = [](auto... values) {
        std::common_type_t<decltype(values)...> ret = {};
        decltype(ret) _[] = { (ret += values)... };
        (void)_;
        return ret;
    };

    auto v = l(0, 0., 5, 4.2);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Return type is given by the `std::common_type_t` of the given pack.
The rest of the code contains the common pattern usually used while waiting for *fold expressions*.

In C++17 it will become:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    auto l = [](auto... values) { return (values + ...); };
    auto v = l(0, 0., 5, 4.2);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MTyYnmP8ChQvkEol).

If you want to verify on the fly that given parameters are all of arithmetic types, you can use the bool trick as it follows:

```
auto l = [](auto... values) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<
            std::integer_sequence<bool, true, std::is_arithmetic<decltype(values)>::value...>,
            std::integer_sequence<bool, std::is_arithmetic<decltype(values)>::value..., true>
        >::value, "!"
    );

    std::common_type_t<decltype(values)...> ret = {};
    decltype(ret) _[] = { (ret += values)... };
    (void)_;
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: Could you please explain what decltype(ret) _[] = { (ret += values)... }; (void)_; is doing?

Comment: @KitFisto It creates a temporary array (to be discarded immediately after). The aim of the statement is to unpack `values` and sum them in `ret`. You can't do it gracefully until C++17, I'm sorry.

Comment: And how is (ret += values)... allowed? It almost looks like a fold operator.

Comment: Why does the cast to void delete the array and why is it necessary?

Comment: @KitFisto `(void)_` doesn't delete the array, you have not to delete it. It's not allocated in the dynamic storage. Its purpose is to silent a warning, nothing more. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm assuming you need a functor-like type to calculate the sum if you're using the lambda. If that's the case then I suppose you could write a small generic class to take the place of that lambda.

```
template < typename T > struct Sum
{
    template < typename U >
    T operator () (U v) const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast< T >(v);
    }

    template < typename U, typename... Values >
    T operator () (U v, Values&&... vs) const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast< T >(v) + (*this)(std::forward< Values >(vs)...);
    }
};
```

And used as:

```
auto sum = Sum< int >();
printf("%d\n", sum(23, 4.0, true, 7));
```

I wrote it in such way that the return type can be specified in advance. But I suppose you could adjust it to make that generic as well.

If this was not your intention then please ignore this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The very purpose of my question was how to do it without explicit use of templates.

Comment: The reason this cannot be implemented with lambdas is that once you call a lambda with a certain set of parameters. The compiler generates a functor-like class with a function call operator matching that set of parameters. Therefore, you cannot call the same lambda from inside itself or anywhere else without passing the same set of parameters. Thus preventing you from popping parameters from the parameter pack.